# How should I handle `deposed` resources in Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform

I am struggling to understand how I should handle `deposed` resources found in my TF state.

In particular, when running an apply, I am now getting some errors like the below:

```
Error applying plan:

11 error(s) occurred:

* aws_instance.mongo-replica-01 (deposed #0): Error terminating instance: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound: The instance ID 'i-0f0bdc2c16e922fbc' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 71b98708-cb06-4f11-ad14-8d3d160fbc1a
* aws_instance.mongo-replica-01 (deposed #1): Error terminating instance: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound: The instance ID 'i-080ef01dc84c09685' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 07c96f82-1e32-4944-a1d6-ab0e6306b82e
* aws_instance.mongo-replica-02 (deposed #1): Error terminating instance: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound: The instance ID 'i-085b997daac742c1e' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: 20ff2b73-39c9-4d49-af41-f4ec542ec782
* aws_instance.mongo-replica-02 (deposed #0): Error terminating instance: InvalidInstanceID.NotFound: The instance ID 'i-00bc7fd15b04a3688' does not exist
    status code: 400, request id: cdea3c4f-9bec-496a-aedd-bcfbf0a706d2
```

The AWS EC2 instances in question do not exist indeed, but TF errors out when trying to delete them (presumably because they don't exist) and still keeps them in the state.

I tried using the `terraform state` command in an attempt to remove the `deposed` resources, but it only allows me to delete the whole resource, not just the `deposed` instance of it...

Am I expected to, simply, manually go in the terraform state file and delete the deposed sections??

Comment: I'm not really sure what you mean by "deposed"? You mean they've been deleted by something other than TF? The default `-refresh=true` parameter to `terraform destroy` should automatically update the state file with what's in AWS and thus remove the missing instances and then not try to destroy them.

Comment: Apparently deposed is a state. See, for example, this issue: https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/9844

Comment: Indeed, documentation is somewhat scarce for the "deposed" state, as indicated in the [github issue here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10753)

Answer (score 14):

From the [GitHub Issue requesting for Documentation about the "deposed" state](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/10753#issuecomment-267638933)

> "Deposed" is the state a resource goes into when Terraform is dealing
>   with create_before_destroy... since there can only be one "primary"
>   instance of a given resource, Terraform will first depose the existing
>   one (so it's still tracked in state but no longer used for
>   interpolations), then create the replacement instance before finally
>   deleting the deposed instance.
>
> Errors during that process can cause the deposed instance to stick in
>   the state, since Terraform doesn't want to lose track of them before
>   it can delete them. However, this behavior was a little inconsistent
>   in earlier Terraform versions, and also Terraform handled deposed
>   instances silently rather than including them in the plan output.
>
> So all of this is to say: these deposed instances are leftovers from a
>   failure during the replacement of these resources with
>   create_before_destroy. If you look in the Terraform state file (either
>   terraform.tfstate or .terraform/terraform.tfstate depending on whether
>   you have remote state enabled) you should find the records of these by
>   searching for the word deposed; you can use the data Terraform has
>   stored for these to decide if they are safe to delete before letting
>   Terraform proceed here.

So, you could infer that the "deposed" state of those resources is merely indicative of an underlying issue that's caused errors during the `destroy` phase.  As mentioned in the quote, the "deposed" resources should be "resolved", for lack of a better term, the next time you run `terraform apply`.  In the meantime, check the `tfstate` files for any/all specific information that terraform has stored to determine if it's safe to proceed and/or to, potentially, diagnose where the problem might be.

Additionally, you can try the following to refresh the local state

```
terraform refresh      Update local state file against real resources
```

Also,

```
terraform debug              Debug output management
terraform state              Advanced state management
```

Comment: terraform destroy and refresh do not do anything for me; `terraform state` list shows 5 resources but `terraform show` indicates all 5 are empty and deposed. Do I remove them with `terraform state rm`? Then there's also a bunch of data objects left. Might just be easier to drop that state (there are no resources left in AWS related to this).

Answer (score 10):

`terraform state rm` followed by `terraform import` removes the deposed object from state.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, after our CI pipelines tried to apply the failing changes multiple times we had:
`aws_eks_node_group.node_group is tainted, so must be replaced`
`aws_eks_node_group.node_group (deposed object 9f3a96cc) will be destroyed`
`aws_eks_node_group.node_group (deposed object bd3de6ba) will be destroyed`
`aws_eks_node_group.node_group (deposed object e0e04d23) will be destroyed`
all of which were cleaned up after
`terraform state rm 'aws_eks_node_group.node_group'`
`terraform import 'aws_eks_node_group.node_group' my-cluster:my-node-group-name`

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue with EC2 instances that I removed, but halted the process mid-way, and what I ended up doing was manually editing my terraform `tfstate` file.

In it, I found the items that were deposed, changed `tainted` to `false` and emptied the `deposed` array.

After running `terraform plan`, the instances were gone from the output.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For my scenario, I wound up disabling `create_before_destroy` (changing from true to false).  Otherwise, I could not figure out where to apply the other solutions and terraform state did not show `deposed` nor `tainted` anywhere.